Find first uncovered debt month in Oracle Sql
I want to find first month in which the debt is not fully covered. I will try to explain:
A subscriber took 10$ debt in July and paid 5$, In August took 5$ and paid 5$, In September took 5$ and paid 2$, In October took 2$ and didn't paid. If the debt is not paid in the current month, then the previous debts should be paid with the next month's payments.  So, July's debt fully covered in august and August's debt not fully covered. So, August must be "first uncover month". How can I write script in oracle SQL to find "first uncover month"?
this is table:
CREATE TABLE debt_payments (
    month VARCHAR2(10),
    debt_taken NUMBER,
    payment NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO debt_payments (month, debt_taken, payment) VALUES ('July', 10, 5);
INSERT INTO debt_payments (month, debt_taken, payment) VALUES ('August', 5, 5);
INSERT INTO debt_payments (month, debt_taken, payment) VALUES ('September', 5, 2);
INSERT INTO debt_payments (month, debt_taken, payment) VALUES ('October', 2, 0);


I wrote this but didn't work real base and only find first month when remaining_debt > 0.
WITH debt_summary AS (
    SELECT 
        month,
        SUM(debt_taken) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS total_debt,
        SUM(payment) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS total_payment
    FROM 
        debt_payments
),
remaining_debt AS (
    SELECT 
        month,
        total_debt - total_payment AS remaining_debt
    FROM 
        debt_summary
)
SELECT 
    month
FROM 
    remaining_debt
WHERE 
    remaining_debt > 0
ORDER BY 
    month
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;  -- Get the first month where debt is uncovered



One of the options could be to use MODEL clause which alows you to address and manipulate sql data pretty much like the data in Excel sheet.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE debt_payments ( month DATE, debt_taken NUMBER, payment NUMBER );
INSERT INTO debt_payments 
  Select DATE '2024-07-01', 10, 5 From Dual Union All
  Select DATE '2024-08-01',  5, 5 From Dual Union All
  Select DATE '2024-09-01',  5, 2 From Dual Union All
  Select DATE '2024-10-01',  2, 0 From Dual;

... assuming that there is one row of data per month ...
--      S Q L : 
SELECT   month, debt_taken, payment, balance
FROM    ( Select     month, debt_taken, payment, Row_Number() Over(Order By month) as rn 
          From       debt_payments
        )
  MODEL    Dimension By ( rn )
           Measures  ( month, debt_taken, payment, 0.00 as next_month_payment, 0.00 balance )
  RULES ( next_month_payment[ANY] = Nvl(CASE WHEN month[CV() + 1] Is Null
                                            THEN 0
                                            WHEN  debt_taken[CV()] - 
                                                  Nvl(Sum(next_month_payment)[rn = CV() - 1], 0) -
                                                  payment[CV()] >= payment[CV() + 1] 
                                            THEN payment[CV() + 1]
                                       ELSE debt_taken[CV()] - 
                                            Nvl(Sum(next_month_payment)[rn = CV() - 1], 0) -
                                            payment[CV()]
                                       END, 0), 
         balance[ANY] = ( debt_taken[CV()] - (payment[CV()] + next_month_payment[CV()]) ) -
                         CASE WHEN payment[CV()] + next_month_payment[CV()] = 0
                              THEN (  ( payment[CV()] - Nvl(next_month_payment[CV() - 1], 0) )   )
                         ELSE 0
                         END
       )

/*      R e s u l t : 
MONTH      DEBT_TAKEN  PAYMENT  BALANCE
---------  ----------  -------  -------
01-JUL-24          10        5        0
01-AUG-24           5        5        5
01-SEP-24           5        2        3
01-OCT-24           2        0        2      */

... select the row with the first month having debt not fully payed (August, balance = 5) ...
See the fiddle here.
More about the MODEL CLAUSE here.

Don't store months as strings - store them as DATEs.
From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   debt_payments
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY month
         MEASURES
           LAST(has_paid.month) AS unpaid_month
         PATTERN ( ^ has_paid* unpaid? )
         DEFINE
           has_paid AS SUM(debt_taken) - debt_taken <= SUM(payment)
       )

In earlier versions you can use analytic functions:
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(MIN(month), -1) AS unpaid_month
FROM   (
  SELECT month,
         SUM(debt_taken) OVER (ORDER BY month) - debt_taken AS prev_debt,
         SUM(payment) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS total_paid
  FROM   debt_payments
)
WHERE  prev_debt > total_paid

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE debt_payments (month, debt_taken, payment) AS
  SELECT DATE '2024-07-01', 10, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-08-01',  5, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-09-01',  5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-10-01',  2, 0 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



UNPAID_MONTH




2024-08-01 00:00:00



fiddle

Thank u but first unpaid month must be  August:  subscriber covered July's debt and not fully covered August's debt. In July The subscriber took a debt of 10 dollars and paid 5 dollars, 5 dollars remained to be paid.  In august, paid 5$ (That means covered July's debt) and took 5$ debt. In September, paid 2$ (That means this amount is not enough to covered July's debt therefor in July remained 3 $) and also took 5$. In Oct took 2$ debt.  To summarize, to this day subscriber has 10$ debt which is not cover from August.

@user18552635 The first month when the debt was not been covered was in September and the debt was from the previous month, August. I've updated the query but you could have used the previous result and subtracted 1 month.
